# Overriding ToString()

Tags: .net, wpf, overriding

Is there a way to override the ToString() method on the Shape class, without inheriting from it and doing it in the the inherited class? So whenever I call any of the shapes' to string method I get the overriden one?

Note I don't want to this:
Shpae1: Shape
override ....

The reason why I wan't to do this, is I have a lot of shapes in my project already, ellipses, rectangles etc (the generic ones). I want to print the location of each shape, I Know I could to a separate function taking a shape as an arg, but I have some code already there that uses the to string of a shape, so I thought it would be more elegant if I could just change the toString method so I won't have to change any of my code.

Comment: Can you give us more details ? You want to use Shape.ToString() without inheriting from Shape ? If so why ?

Comment: OP says question is not WPF specific. What now ?

Comment: @PetarRepac: No; the OP did not say that.

Comment: @Petar: If you want to see who changed what, you simply need to click on the [edited-link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8639065/revisions) to see the revisions. Actually Slaks removed the WPF-Tag and added it again ;)

Comment: @PetarRepac I added the explanation above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible (also there might be some dirty reflection tricks involving dynamic code generation etc.)

The main ways to extend an existing class like `Shape` are:

1. **Inherit**. This is not possible because you use `Rectangle`, `Ellipse` etc. which are sealed.
2. **Partial class**. Does not work because .NET does not provide `Shape`, `Rectangle`, etc. as partial classes.
3. **Extension method**. Would be the most elegant solution but does not work either because extension methods are only used if the class does not provide the method itself. And `ToString()` is provided in `System.Object` that every class inherits from, so technically `Shape`, `Rectangle`, etc. have a `ToString()` method, even if they do not override them themselves.

So i would consider one of the two options:

- Create a static method `string GetStringInfo(Shape s)` in a utility class that takes a `Shape` and returns the string, then use this function everywhere you use `ToString()` on a `Shape`.
- To minimize refactoring, create an extension method `string GetStringInfo()` on type `Shape` and refactor your code to use this method instead of `ToString()`

If anyone knows another working solution, I'd be interested in that, too.

Comment: +1 - point 3. and the second bullet point seems the most elegant solution alright

Answer (score 0):

No; you can't do that.

Instead, you should probably use a DataTemplate.

Comment: Seems that OP removed WPF tag.

Comment: @PetarRepac: Actually, I did, since it wasn't relevant to the question.  Do you think I should put it back?

Comment: I think that Slakses answer is in WPF context.

Comment: @SLaks i see what you are saying with the data template.

Comment: @SLaks: confused :), this DataTemplate is a WPF thing ? If so, you answered in WPF context and then removed the WPF tag ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Shape as internal field of your class and in your ToString() method call _shape.ToString().

Comment: Which is the same as inheriting Shape and overriding ToString()

Comment: No, it is not. If you inherit from Shape, your class will publish all public members Shape has. And you cannot hide them. If you contain an Shape instance inside your class you can pick what members you want to be accessible to clients of your class. E.g. if Shape has method Draw() your class could hide this method.

Comment: This is a control. You think it's a good practice not to inherit control, but rather keep them as private fields?

Comment: No, I don't think so. But I was answering a question "Is there a way to override the ToString() method on the Shape class, without inheriting from it...". At that moment WPF tag was not present and I thought that the question is on inheritance.